# Foreign keys in android 2.2 and higher

Tags: android

In android 2.2 and higher SQLite supports foreign keys but they are disabled by default.
In my application I use database.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON"); every time after open database.

I have two questions:

1. Why are foreign keys disabled by default?
2. Have you better solution to enable foreign keys?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to do it every time?  I thought it was set when the DB was created, so you only needed to.do it then...

Comment: I do it every time after open database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreign keys are disabled by default in stock SQLite also (for backwards compatibility) - I think it even says so in the SQLite FK documentation. So Android is simply *not* messing with the default behaviour.

The `PRAGMA` is the correct way to enable foreign key support.